# Public member function return inner class?

Tags: c++, return, inner-classes

I am working on a simple Set class as a project to get familiar with implementing and writing my own Iterators. I have the Set class fully fleshed out, and I have been told that a good way to create an Iterator is to have an inner class Iterator, which is what I have done.

```
#include "homemadeSet.h"
Set::Set{
//etc
}

Set::Iterator::Iterator(){}

Set::Iterator Set::begin(){

    //return Iterator
}
```

Here is a really truncated part of my code. I am trying to have the set's public member function begin() return a inner class Iterator.

**Edit: Sorry, my question is what is the syntax for returning the inner class?**

Thanks for the answers, sometimes the easiest solution eludes you^^.

Comment: Exactly what is it you are struggling with? As long as Set::Iterator is made public, it should just work.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea so far.  What's the problem or question?

Comment: are you asking about the "this" pointer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an object of type `Set::Iterator` using an appropriate constructor, and return it.  For example, if `Iterator` has

```
public:
    Iterator();
    explicit Iterator(InternalStuff*);
```

you could do

```
Set::Iterator Set::begin() const {
    return Iterator(mFirstElement);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes do not differ from top-level classes in the way you create or return them. The name of the outer class becomes a part of the fully qualified name of the inner class, so you need to use the scope resolution operator `::` to build up the name.

```
Set::Iterator Set::begin(){
    Set::Iterator res;
    // prepare the Iterator, for example
    // res.setPosition(0);
    return res;
}
```